# Structuring Python software with fluent interface

Tags: python

I'm trying to create my first Python Project, which is a software to make some adjustments in a database file (gdb file).

The idea to structure the code is the following:

In my main function i create a MAP dict, which will be populate from function to function, like so:

```
def phase2(MAP):
  # do something
  return MAP

def phase1(MAP):
  # do something...
  return MAP

def main():
  MAP = {}
  phase1_result = phase1(MAP)
  phase2_result = phase2(phase1_result)
```

And so on... like an fluent interface. My question is: is there a better approach to call a function passing the result from another? The idea is avoid changing global variables, avoiding side effects.

Thanks!

Comment: We generally solve this problem (which relates much to increasing the complexity of your program), by going [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Encapsulation is the keyword here.

Comment: Are you just altering the object? Then there's no need to `return` it, the alterations will be visible on the originally passed object. Secondarily, why not write a `class`? `m = Map(); m.phase1(); m.phase2()`